# Recover Partitions deleted by rm

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, ntfs, rm

In my PC I have 3 NTFS partitions
1 for Windows Boot Loader, next one is windows installation directory and the last one is for storing my whole data.

They were mounted like this

> /dev/sda1 => /mnt/sda1
>
> /dev/sda2 => /mnt/sda2
>
> /dev/sda3 => /mnt/sda3

Yesterday I accidentally used following command

> `rm -rf /mnt/sda1 /mnt/sda2 /mnt/sda3`

and now, When I am trying to open the Data partition it shows **Input/Output error**

Can I recover my data???

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools for data recovery but the key here is to don't touch anything, create a live usb/cd on another machine and use that. I recommend testdisk it can be found on gparted liveCD. Both are free.

Comment: Hm okay I will do it.. thanks for your response. :)

Answer (score 1):

First: **get that disk out of the machine**, put it in an external USB case, and only use it to access data, don't ever write to it.

Several months ago I partitioned an Ubuntu laptop and installed Windows on it. Then the owner told me to recover files from it. I used **[Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)** to recover the files. Almost all files were recovered. Filenames, paths to the file, and file dates were gone, so depending on what you're looking for this might be a problem. It does recognize filetypes, so jpeg, doc etc is identified and can be filtered out.

Comment: Yeah, I tried testdisk, it can recover the deleted files. But I have some files left in the partition, So can I fix the input/output error without formatting the partition??

Comment: I used Photorec to recover files (all types of files, not just photos despite the name). I haven't used Testdisk. I didn't have problems with I/O, and formatted the disk in the end. I don't think Testdisk will fix your I/O problems. Testdisk and Photorec can be used to recover files, other tools exist to fix or analyze disk and I/O problems.

Comment: Hm.. right!! anyway thankyou for the answer.

Comment: First recover files, then mess with the disk!